# Solving a system of linear equations having infinitely many solutions.

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

\begin{align}
x-\hphantom{2}y+2z+2t&=0 \\
2x-2y+4z+3t&=1 \\
3x-3y+6z+9t&=-3 \\
4x-4y+8z+8t&=0
\end{align}

Solve for x,y,z and t

[image: reduced row echelon form]

Comment: i used the Gauss Jordan elimination to obtain the reduced row echelon form of the matrix and i ended up with two zero rows.
Meaning x,y and z are free variables.
i don't know what to do next.

Comment: i'm sorry.Im a newbie.
I'll edit the post.

Comment: @TeynidhiRamsewak Since you're using Math SE, You're not newbie anymore.

Comment: @DigitalBrain thanks :)

Comment: @TeynidhiRamsewak We're not allowed to discuss it here, So, I;m deleting my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then treat any two variables as constants and express other two in terms of those constants

For Example if you keep $x$ and $y$ as constants then
$$z=\frac{y-x+2}{2}$$
$$t=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$2x-2y+4z+4t=0$
$2x-2y+4z+3t=1$
Then we get that t=-1 .
And after that all equations become :

$x-y+2z=2$
 So we have  $t=-1$ and $x=2+y-2z$ , where $y$ and $z$ can be everything